# Plotting Theoretical Maximum ratio combining

Tags: theory, diversity

I am try to plot the maximum ratio combining of BPSK on a Rayleigh fading channel by integration i.e,

$$
\bar{P_e} = \int_0^\infty Q(\sqrt{2\gamma})p_\Sigma(\gamma) \ d\gamma
$$
but I can't seem to get the same as the closed form answer.

$$
\bar{P_e} = \left( \frac{1 - T}{2}\right)^M \sum_{m=0}^{M-1} \begin{pmatrix}
M - 1 + m \\
m
\end{pmatrix}\left( \frac{1 + T}{2}\right)^m
$$

[image]

Here is my code:

```
def Q(x):
    """
    Q function
    """
    return 0.5 * math.erfc(x / math.sqrt(2))

def p_b_intgrate(M, snr_db):
    """
    Maximum ratio combining BER
    """
    inf = 1000
    gamma_bar = 10.**(snr_db/10) * inf # Convert SNR from dB to linear scale
    p_gamma = lambda gamma: (gamma**(M-1)*np.exp(-gamma/gamma_bar))/(gamma_bar**(M)*np.math.factorial(M-1))
    gamma = np.linspace(0, inf, 1000)
    p_b = np.sum([p_gamma(g)  * Q(np.sqrt(2 * g)) for g in gamma])
    return p_b

def p_b_closed(M, snr_db):
    """
    Maximum ratio combining BER
    """
    snr_linear = 10.**(snr_db/10) # Convert SNR from dB to linear scale
    T = np.sqrt(snr_linear/ (1 + snr_linear)) 
    ncr = np.array([comb(M-1 + m, m) for m in range(M)]) # Number of combinations
    m = np.arange(0, M) # Index for the selected antenna
    ber = ((1 - T) / 2)**M * np.sum(ncr * ((1+T)/2) ** m)
    return ber

# =======================
snr_db = np.linspace(-10, 40, 100) # range of SNR values in dB
mrc_ber_int = [p_b_intgrate(1, snr) for snr in snr_db]
mrc_ber_closed = [p_b_closed(1, snr) for snr in snr_db]

plt.figure()
plt.plot(snr_db, mrc_ber_int, label='MRC, M=1')
plt.plot(snr_db, mrc_ber_closed, label='MRC, M=1, Closed')
plt.xlabel('SNR (dB)')
plt.ylabel('$P_e$')
plt.yscale("log")
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why do you multiply by inf when converting to linear power from dB? When you do the approximate integration by summation, don’t you also need to multiply by the step in gamma (which is conveniently 1 in your current step size)?

Comment: @DanBoschen don't you need to integrate it from 0 to $\gamma_0$ i was assume that is the case. Also I could multiply it by the step in gamma but it is still quite far off the theoretical

Comment: your formula shows integrating to $\infty$ over all possible $\gamma$ weighted by the occurrence of each. I couldn't get it to match theoretical either which is why I deleted my answer, but those two pointes jumped out at me. (The step won't effect your implementation as you step by 1 but it should if you change the step size).

Comment: I see. Seems like the only way to align with the theoretical is through brute force simulations but mathematically it seems hard to align it theoretically which is kind of weird to me.

Comment: I agree and believe it should match mathematically- I reviewed your formulation and find no flaws beyond what I mentioned and tried myself but could not get it to match. I am watching this post with interest